# C++ Segmentation Fault in Creating a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to insert a new node at the end of a linked list. However, when I try, I get a segmentation fault at what would be the point of insertion. I know that the preferred method is the 'head -> next' style, but for the assignment, we're stuck doing it long hand. Help?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct NodeType;
typedef NodeType *NodePtr;

struct NodeType
{
   int data;
   NodePtr next;
};

int main ()
{
   NodePtr head;
   NodePtr temp;
   NodePtr tempTwo;
   NodePtr tempThree;
   NodePtr tempFour;

   head = new NodeType;
   (*head).data = 5;
   (*head).next = NULL;

   temp = new NodeType;
   (*temp).data = 8;
   (*temp).next = head;
   head = temp;
   delete temp;

   tempTwo = new NodeType;
   (*tempTwo).data = 12;
   (*tempTwo).next = NULL;
   head -> next -> next = tempTwo;
   delete tempTwo;






}
```

Comment: remember: access a memory that has been free causes Undefined behavior at run time

Answer (score 4):

```
delete temp;
delete tempTwo;
```

Remove these lines. You are deleting the memory you allocate, so that the next time you access it through `head` you get **segfault**.

You need to `delete` the blocks of memory you allocate, and this should happen after you are done using the memory. You don't need to `delete` every variable that touches that memory.

In your case, you can make a loop at the end of the `main` function which deletes the elements one by one (you need to save the `next` pointer first)

Comment: Ideally, wouldn't that statement come in the destructor?  Without the `delete` statement, the memory isn't being returned to the system when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: @RichardD he could make a recursive destructor in his `Node` class, but it is probably preferable to do it iteratively at the end of the main function as I advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
head = temp; // head and temp point to same object
delete temp; // object temp points to is de-allocated
```

you delete the object that `temp` points to, which is the same object that `head` points to. Then you de-reference `head` here:

```
head -> next -> next = tempTwo;
```

But `head` doesn't point to anything valid. De-referencing it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In the code

```
 temp = new NodeType;
   (*temp).data = 8;
   (*temp).next = head;
   head = temp;
   delete temp;
```

what is assigned to `head` is deleted. so here `head` point to garbage.So the line  `head -> next -> next = tempTwo;` gives you segmentation fault. You are assigning to an invalid location.

Answer (score 0):

```
   head = temp;
   delete temp;
```

-- you delete the pointer and deference it later on

```
   head -> next -> next = tempTwo;
```